# Cloudformation packages install on ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I want to install awslogs packages in ubuntu instance but as given in AWS documentation they are using yum for that like shown below in code (for amazon linux).
My Question for that is

I am using ubuntu can I use apt-get awslogs to install this package . just need to place apt-get instead of yum ..if not then what is the solution to install awslogs in ubuntu using CFN

```
 Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration'
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Init':
        configSets:
          default: !If [HasIAMUserSSHAccess, [awslogs, ssh-access, mount, extras, config], [awslogs, mount, extras, config]]
        awslogs:
          packages:
            yum:
              awslogs: []
          files:
            '/etc/awslogs/awscli.conf':
              content: !Sub |
                [default]
                region = ${AWS::Region}
                [plugins]
                cwlogs = cwlogs
              mode: '000644'
              owner: root
              group: root
            '/etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf':
```

Comment: Might be relevant: [How To Setup AWS Logs Agent on Ubuntu 16.04 Instance](https://devopscube.com/setup-aws-logs-agent-ubuntu-16/)

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use JUST apt instead of apt-get